# A Jacobi field along a geodesic segment is the variation field of a family of geodesics

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I am reading an introductory textbook in Riemannian geometry (Lee), and met this problem:

> Any Jacobi field $V$ along a geodesic segment $\gamma$ is the variation field of some variation of $\gamma$ through geodesics.

A hint is given: try to write the family $\Gamma (s,t)$ as $\exp_{\sigma(s)}tW(s)$ for some proper curve $\sigma(s)$ and vector field $W(s)$ along $\sigma$. This is reasonable since for each $s$, $\Gamma (s,t)$ gives a geodesic.

The problem is of course how to find such $\sigma$ and $W$. Clearly we should require $\dot \sigma (0) = V(0)$, and $W(0)$ be determined by the original geodesic $\gamma$. But what's next? I plan to find $\partial / \partial t \ \Gamma $ and $\partial / \partial s\  \Gamma $, and see whether I can get something from the Jacobi equation. But I do not know how to differentiate  $\exp$ with respect to $\sigma(s)$!

Anyone has more hint(s)? Thank a lot!

Comment: Hint: Two Jacobi fields along the same geodesic are equal if and only if their initial values and their initial covariant derivatives coincide.

Comment: @JackLee Thank you! I think I now get it!

Comment: Without the hint, my gut would have said to do the usual thing where we set $\Gamma(s,t) = \exp_{\gamma(t)} sV(t)$. Now it's clear that $V$ is the variation field, the acceleration $D_t^2 \Gamma$ is zero when $s=0$ by assumption, and the Jacobi equation tells us $D_s$ of the acceleration is $0$ at $s=0$. Can I extend this? Is this necessarily a variation through geodesics?